# How to apply $casts converting to pivot column with manyToMany relationships in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.3

I have problem with apply **$casts to pivot column** in laravel 5.3. I using manyToMany relationships.
My 3 DB tables:

```
users - contain: id,…other columns
books - contain: id,…other columns
book_user (pivot table) - contain: book_id, user_id, options
“options” is JSON type.
```

I want use $casts to converting my pivot column **options** to json_encode/json_decode.
Example:

```
$casts = ['pivotColumn.options'=>'array']
```

My models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        books.pivot.options' => 'array',
    ];

    public function books() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Book’)->withPivot('options');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        users.pivot.options' => 'array',
    ];

    public function books() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User’)->withPivot('options');
    }
}
```

I found that the version 5.1 and higher you can use dot notation for pivot casts.
Example:

```
protected $casts = [
    books.pivot.options' => 'array',
];
```

I tried more variant but nothing. It is not working :/.

Can you help me please?
Thank you for each answer.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this similar question, I wish Laravel has something to offer on this.